# here-document gives 'unexpected end of file' error

Tags: bash, email, heredoc

I need my script to send an email from terminal. Based on what I've seen here and many other places online, I formatted it like this:

```
/var/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" << EOF
Here's a line of my message!
And here's another line!
Last line of the message here!
EOF
```

However, when I run this I get this warning:

```
myfile.sh: line x: warning: here-document at line y delimited by end-of-file (wanted 'EOF')

myfile.sh: line x+1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

...where line x is the last written line of code in the program, and line y is the line with `/var/mail` in it. I've tried replacing `EOF` with other things (`ENDOFMESSAGE`, `FINISH`, etc.) but to no avail. Nearly everything I've found online has it done this way, and I'm really new at bash so I'm having a hard time figuring it out on my own. Could anyone offer any help?

Comment: Is the `EOF` line indented? It has to be at the beginning of the line.

Comment: It is, but only as far as that entire statement is nested. So it has to be all the way to the left?

Comment: Also, ensure no trailing characters (including carriage return!)

Comment: If you indent with *only* tab characters, you can use `<<-EOF` -- http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents

Answer (score 218, accepted):

The `EOF` token must be at the beginning of the line, you can't indent it along with the block of code it goes with.

If you write `<<-EOF` you may indent it, but it must be indented with <kbd>Tab</kbd> characters, not spaces. So it still might not end up even with the block of code.

Also make sure you have no whitespace **after** the `EOF` token on the line.

Comment: In the code example above, the EOF token is at the beginning of the line.

Comment: I don't see it in the edit history, but it must have been indented originally, because I wasn't the only one to point out this problem.

Comment: I get this error even when I remove all unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: Check for CR characters, and use `dos2unix` to fix it.

Comment: Hey Me! The space after EOF always gets me at my job (modifying scripts)... I'll be back here... See you again in a few months!

Answer (score 22):

The line that starts or ends the here-doc probably has some non-printable or whitespace characters (for example, carriage return) which means that the second "EOF" does not match the first, and doesn't end the here-doc like it should. This is a very common error, and difficult to detect with just a text editor. You can make non-printable characters visible for example with `cat`:

```
cat -A myfile.sh
```

Once you see the output from `cat -A` the solution will be obvious: remove the offending characters.

Answer (score 9):

Please try to remove the preceeding spaces before `EOF`:-

```
/var/mail -s "$SUBJECT" "$EMAIL" <<-EOF
```

Using `<tab>` instead of `<spaces>` for ident AND using <<-EOF works fine.

The `"-"` removes the `<tabs>`, not `<spaces>`, but at least this works.

Comment: The first suggestion won't help (did you test to see whether space causes a problem?). The second will only help if the EOF line is indented with TAB, not spaces.

Comment: I think that the terminating token must not have leading spaces

Answer (score 4):

For anyone stumbling here who [googled "bash warning: here-document delimited by end-of-file"](https://www.google.com/search?q=bash%20warning%3A%20here-document%20delimited%20by%20end-of-file&oq=bash%20warning%3A%20here-document%20%20delimited%20by%20end-of-file&aqs=chrome..69i57.5672j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), it may be that you are getting the

> warning: here-document at line 74 delimited by end-of-file

...type warning because *you accidentally used a **here document** symbol (`<<`) when you meant to use a **here string** symbol (`<<<`).* That was my case.

Answer (score 2):

Note one can also get this error if you do this;

```
while read line; do
  echo $line
done << somefile
```

Because `<< somefile` should read `< somefile` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

May be old but I had a space after the ending EOF
 << EOF
blah
blah
EOF   <-- this was the issue.  Had it for years, finally looked it up here

Answer (score 0):

When I want to have *docstrings* for my bash functions, I use a solution similar to the suggestion of [user12205](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3488231/user12205) in a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815600/indenting-heredocs-with-spaces) of this question.

See how I define USAGE for a solution that:

- auto-formats well for me in my IDE of choice (sublime)
- is multi-line
- can use spaces or tabs as indentation
- preserves indentations within the comment.

```
function foo {
    # Docstring
    read -r -d '' USAGE <<'    END'
        # This method prints foo to the terminal.
        #
        # Enter `foo -h` to see the docstring.
        #      It has indentations and multiple lines.
        #
        # Change the delimiter if you need hashtag for some reason.
        # This can include $$ and = and eval, but won't be evaluated
    END


    if [ "$1" = "-h" ]
    then
        echo "$USAGE" | cut -d "#" -f 2 | cut -c 2-
        return
    fi

    echo "foo"
}
```

So `foo -h` yields:

```
This method prints foo to the terminal.

Enter `foo -h` to see the docstring.
     It has indentations and multiple lines.

Change the delimiter if you need hashtag for some reason.
This can include $$ and = and eval, but won't be evaluated
```

**Explanation**

`cut -d "#" -f 2`: Retrieve the second portion of the `#` delimited lines.  *(Think a csv with "#" as the delimiter, empty first column).*

`cut -c 2-`: Retrieve the 2nd to end character of the resultant string

Also note that `if [ "$1" = "-h" ]` evaluates as `False` if there is no first argument, w/o error, since it becomes an empty string.

Answer (score -1):

Along with the other answers mentioned by Barmar and Joni, I've noticed that I sometimes have to leave a blank line before and after my EOF when using `<<-EOF`.

Comment: I find no support for this in either theory or practice. Downvoting as superstition.

Comment: I had a multiline here-doc wrapped in parens to redirect to `cat` and due to the formatting, right before my closing here-doc marker I needed to add an enter before the closing paren otherwise I'd get this mismatch. Upvoting as completely valid for "some" folks out there, albeit probably an unlikely scenario.

Comment: I hate to contribute to superstition, but I also was having this issue, and added a blank line after the end of my EOF.  (ubuntu 19.10 running in docker; this was in a bootstrap.sh script). The blank line fixed this error.

Comment: This also fixed my issue when passing yaml files to GCP cloudbuild

Answer (score -1):

Here is a flexible way to do deal with multiple indented lines **without** using heredoc.

```
  echo 'Hello!'
  sed -e 's:^\s*::' < <(echo '
    Some indented text here.
    Some indented text here.
  ')
  if [[ true ]]; then
    sed -e 's:^\s\{4,4\}::' < <(echo '
      Some indented text here.
        Some extra indented text here.
      Some indented text here.
    ')
  fi
```

Some notes on this solution:

- if the content is expected to have simple quotes, either escape them using `\` or replace the string delimiters with double quotes. In the latter case, be careful that construction like `$(command)` will be interpreted. If the string contains both simple and double quotes, you'll have to escape at least of kind.
- the given example print a trailing empty line, there are numerous way to get rid of it, not included here to keep the proposal to a minimum clutter
- the flexibility comes from the ease with which you can control how much leading space should stay or go, provided that you know some sed REGEXP of course.