# How to add a crontab job to crontab using a bash script with date stamp?

Tags: bash, cron

here was the original question
[How to add a crontab job to crontab using a bash script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42198960/how-to-add-a-crontab-job-to-crontab-using-a-bash-script/56332079#56332079)

```
 #!/bin/bash
cronjob="* * * * * /path/to/command"
(crontab -u userhere -l; echo "$cronjob" ) | crontab -u userhere -
```

if I try to use command below bash is importing command and replacing (date +\%H_\%M-\%d.\%m.\%Y at the date and time of the import and I see imported command with fixed date stamp as..../mysql/21_18-27.05.2019_dbbackup.sql.gz

is there a way to keep date imported a formula?

```
cronjob="05 21 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u mysqluserhere -pmysqlpassword DBname | gzip > /path/to/mysql/$(date +\%H_\%M-\%d.\%m.\%Y)_dbbackup.sql.gz" (crontab -u userhere -l; echo "$cronjob" ) | crontab -u userhere -
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can

a) escape the $ in the path, like this:

```
    /path/to/mysql/\$(date +\%H_\%M-\%d.\%m.\%Y)_dbbackup.sql.gz
```

this way the "$(date..." will end up in the cron tab

b) put the whole command into a shellscript(file) and then just execute that file from the cronjob

Answer (score 0):

Using single quotes instead of double around the string will prevent the shell from interpolating anything.

Minimally, switch to single quotes around the variable assignment:

```
cronjob='05 21 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u mysqluserhere -pmysqlpassword DBname | gzip > /path/to/mysql/$(date +\%H_\%M-\%d.\%m.\%Y)_dbbackup.sql.gz'
(crontab -u userhere -l; echo "$cronjob" ) |
crontab -u userhere -
```

though of course, a variable you only use once is rather pointless.

```
(crontab -u userhere -l
 echo '05 21 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u mysqluserhere -pmysqlpassword DBname | gzip > /path/to/mysql/$(date +\%H_\%M-\%d.\%m.\%Y)_dbbackup.sql.gz' ) |
crontab -u userhere -
```

You probably don't need the full path to `mysqldump` either.

Comment: sorry don't see how to insert code in comments. perfect! thanks a lot! also probably shorter command will be (crontab -l ; echo '05 21 * * * /usr/bin/mysqldump -u mysqluserhere -pmysqlpassword DBname | gzip > /path/to/mysql/$(date +\%H_\%M-\%d.\%m.\%Y)_dbbackup.sql.gz') | crontab -

Comment: is there a way to insert in to the beginning of the file rather then to the end?

Comment: Of course; just switch the order of the commands inside the parentheses.

Comment: Hi no what I asked was can I instruct to insert the command on the very fisrt line in file prior even the green text this file # Edit this file to introduce tasks to be run by cron.
.... so it is easy to see when you open the file. At the moment it posts after all the green text in file.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by green text; plain text does not have colors or other formatting facilities. `(echo x; crontab -l)` produces a file where the first line is `x` followed by the user's crontab. That sounds like exactly what you are describing; if it's not, can you find a different way to explain how it's wrong?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33815600/indenting-heredocs-with-spaces has some ideas for preserving indentation in here documents, if that's what you are alluding to. Maybe also explore `printf -v variable '\t%s\n' "first line" "second line" "third line"` etc.