# Script to connect to FTP in a shell

Tags: shell, ftp, redhat

I have to test out some FTP issues and so I was looking at writing this script which will loop through x times, sleep a random number of seconds and continue. I am looking at samples and this is what I came up with but can't get it to run. Any ideas on what is wrong with the script?

```
#! /bin/bash
HOST='host'
USER='user'
PASSWD='password'

i=1
while [[ $i -le 25 ]]
  do
    echo "$i"
    ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
    quote USER $USER
    quote PASS $PASSWD
    bye
    x=$(( ($RANDOM % 4) + 1))
    echo "Sleeping $x number of seconds";
    sleep $x
    let i=i+1;
    EOT
  done
exit 0
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [here-document delimited by end-of-file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660798/here-document-delimited-by-end-of-file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The heredoc end marker `EOT` is in the wrong place.  Correct it like here:

```
#! /bin/bash
HOST='host'
USER='user'
PASSWD='password'

i=1
while [[ $i -le 25 ]]
  do
    echo "$i"
    ftp -n -v $HOST << EOT
    quote USER $USER
    quote PASS $PASSWD
    bye
```

EOT

```
    x=$(( ($RANDOM % 4) + 1))
    echo "Sleeping $x number of seconds"
    sleep $x
    let i=i+1
  done
exit 0
```

Comment: You might want to check [the Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for recurring questions before posting answers to common ones. Nominating as a duplicate helps focus effort on one question and one canonical set of well-researched, debugged answers, often with coverage of multiple aspects and solution techniques.  And thanks for your contributions so far!

Comment: Agreed @tripleee.  I will keep that in mind.  I am relatively new to SO.

Comment: @codeforester thank you for the answer. that helped.