# heredoc gives 'unexpected end of file' error

Tags: bash, syntax, heredoc

I'm creating a Bash script file on iOS X that asks the user if they would like to upload a file to a server. The sftp command (with a delimiter) works fine outside the if statement but when I put the sftp command (with the delimiter) inside the if statement, I get this error message: "upload.sh: line nnn: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

```
printf "Upload file? [y]es?"
read -r input1
if [ $input1 == "y" ] || [ $input1 == "yes" ]; then
  sftp -i key.txt user@server << DELIMITER
    put local/path/to/file /server/upload/dir
    quit
  DELIMITER
fi
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: Don't indent the end of heredoc marker (`DELIMITER`).  Get your script checked through shellcheck.net.

Answer (score 3):

The heredoc marker shouldn't be indented (I assume you are using spaces for indentation).  Rewrite your code this way:

```
printf "Upload file? [y]es?"
read -r input1
if [ "$input1" == "y" ] || [ "$input1" == "yes" ]; then
  sftp -i key.txt user@server << DELIMITER
    put local/path/to/file /server/upload/dir
    quit
DELIMITER
fi
```

It's important to enclose your variable in double quotes to prevent issues arising from word splitting, globbing, and an empty string breaking your test (`[ ... ]`) command.

---

See also:

- [here-document gives 'unexpected end of file' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660798/here-document-gives-unexpected-end-of-file-error)

Comment: Thanks @codeforester! I was unaware of the indentation issue with heredoc markers.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use <kbd>TAB</kbd> indents with heredoc then the redirection operator `<<` should be followed by a `-` (dash), resulting in `<<-`. Any leading <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the heredoc will then be ignored.

```
printf "Upload file? [y]es?"
read -r input1
if [ "$input1" = "y" ] || [ "$input1" = "yes" ]; then
    sftp -i key.txt user@server <<- DELIMITER
        put local/path/to/file /server/upload/dir
        quit
    DELIMITER
fi
```

An alternative would be simple input redirection which could be used instead of heredoc:

```
printf "Upload file? [y]es?"
read -r input1
if [ "$input1" = "y" ] || [ "$input1" = "yes" ]; then
  sftp -i key.txt user@server < \
  <(echo "put local/path/to/file /server/upload/dir ; quit")
fi
```

Also there's no reason to use `==`; use `=` instead when comparing strings within single brackets. If using double brackets the meaning changes, so it's usually better habit to use it consistently.