# Bash Script warning - HERE document delimited by end of file

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a sql file like below

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cat <<'VERBATIM_SQL'
INSERT INTO t_random VALUES (generate_series(1,9999999999), md5(random()::text));
VERBATIM_SQL
```

The sql file is getting called like below from a shell script

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

./insert.sql | psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -d vnera
./insert.sql | psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -d vnera
./insert.sql | psql -U postgres -p 5432 -h localhost -d vnera
```

On executing I am getting a warning like below

```
Loop 1./insert.sql: line 5: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `VERBATIM_SQL')
```

Can someone let me know why is this warning coming?

**EDIT**

I did what was suggested in one of the comments

```
support@vrni-platform:~/postgres_junk$ dos2unix insert.sql
dos2unix: converting file insert.sql to Unix format ...
```

But still getting the same warning

```
./insert.sql: line 5: warning: here-document at line 3 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `VERBATIM_SQL')
```

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18660798/3776858

Comment: In particular, make sure that your file does not have windows line endings.

Comment: DOS line endings wouldn't cause this problem, unless they weren't consistently used. `VERBATIM_SQL\r` would be a valid delimiter and used in both places.

Comment: Oh, though if DOS line endings are being used, it's probable(?) that the last line doesn't have a CRLF terminating it like the previous lines do.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/31886144/1126841, but I'm not sure enough to close unilaterally.

Comment: so, put another way, try `dos2unix insert.sql` and then retry your test. Good luck.

Comment: I did dos2unix still getting same waning.

Comment: @tuk: OK. Also make sure that there is no whitespace following `VERBATIM_SQL` in the last line.

Comment: @rici - Thanks. Whitespace following `VERBATIM_SQL` was the issue. Can you post your comments as an answer so that I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shells are very picky about what they will accept as a here-doc termination. It must precisely match the supplied token. In particular, you should check that:

- The termination line does not have Windows line-ending
- There is no trailing whitespace on the termination line. (It also must not be indented.)