# cat EOF issues with indentation

Tags: bash, docker-compose, aws-cloudformation, cat, heredoc

> **NOTE:** If anyone feel this question has been answered before please paste your answer below otherwise please don't interfere with people
>   trying to help someone who needs help. Thanks

I am not sure why it is such an hassle trying to cat content to file when the content is indented

Can anyone point to how to close this heredoc block

```
UserData:
  "Fn::Base64":
    !Sub |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      NONCE=$(cat /tmp/nonce)
      cat <<-EOF > /tmp/docker-compose.yaml
      version: '3.5'
      services:
      onboarding:
          container_name: nginx
          image: nginx:${BuildId}
          restart: always
            ports:
            - 80:80
          environment:
            ENV: ${Env}
            AWS_REGION: ${Region}
            NONCE: $NONCE
      EOF
      source ~/.bashrc
```

But issue is cat is not closed properly with the closing "EOF".

Content of the file `/tmp/docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: '3.5'
services:
onboarding:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:${BuildId}
    restart: always
      ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      ENV: ${Env}
      AWS_REGION: ${Region}
      NONCE: $NONCE
EOF
source ~/.bashrc
```

but this is what am expecting to see

```
version: '3.5'
services:
onboarding:
    container_name: nginx
    image: nginx:${BuildId}
    restart: always
      ports:
      - 80:80
    environment:
      ENV: ${Env}
      AWS_REGION: ${Region}
      NONCE: $NONCE
```

First why is this heredoc not so simple even with indentations? I know it works fine when there are no spaces at all in the content but man not sure why it is such a hassle when content has spaces

Any better alternative as am about to give up on cat because of this problem

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: no not same..that question has no indentation...that one is easy...when the content has indentations as shown in my question is a problem

Comment: Different question, same answers. Use tabs, not spaces, and don't indent your closing string.

Comment: i used tabs already..as you can see i added the `>>-EOF` because they mentioned using tabs for the spaces.i did that and no did not work...i have spent way too many hours on this thing and it is annoying that am spending hours on something i have no logical reason why it should not just work

Comment: you can paste your answer you believe will work and i can try it and see..i posted all the code above in the question..if you feel confident your answer will work post it and i will try it..thanks for trying to help

Comment: I just gave you two reasons why it won't work. "Use tabs, not spaces, and don't indent your closing string." I'm not going to answer the question because I believe it should be closed.

Comment: i used tabs..not sure if the question does not show as tabs but i used tabs and what you mean by closing string?

Comment: The EOF that terminates the heredoc. And the question code makes it looks like it has spaces, sorry to misunderstand that.

Comment: this is part of cloudformation template..i posted the userdata part which is where am applying the `cat`..so maybe paste what you think i can try in the answer section? and i can try it

Comment: you plan posting an answer?

Comment: @miken32 i keep telling you there is no question that is same as my question..if you feel so then paste an answer to try and i will tell you if it solves the issue..please remove the header because that is false statement

Comment: But @miken32 already posted the answer! "don't indent your closing string... The `EOF` that terminates the heredoc". As one of the above mentioned answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18660985/2886891says: "The `EOF` token must be at the beginning of the line, you can't indent it along with the block of code it goes with."

Comment: it did not work..i think i mentioned that already..again if you have an answer please post it below in this post and i will try it and if it works i will mark as answer...stop telling me there is an answer somewhere...the content of file is docker-compose and it needs to follow certain indentation as well

Comment: i tend to spend more time going back and forth with you mods rather than engaging with ppl trying to answer my question...the experience is just declining gradually every time now...sometimes i feel the mods do not even understand question but look at title and think questions are same..if you are technical enough to understand my question then you will take more steps back and again post your answer and lets see then

Comment: Yep. closing EOF will give an error if its indented.

Answer (score -4):

You have written `<<-EOF`, when I think you meant to write `<<EOF`.

Bash isn't closing your heredoc because it expects `-EOF` to close it, because of how you opened the heredoc. Either change the ending from `EOF` to `-EOF`, or, and this is what I'd suggest, change `<<-EOF` to `<<EOF`.

Comment: i tried `>>EOF` already and many other things...so `>>EOF` did not work either

Comment: `<<-` is valid syntax.

Comment: @uberrebu I was wrong about what I said (sorry), but have you tried removing all the space before the `EOF`? As in, moving it all the way to the left. It's worth a shot, I think.

Comment: that is a part of cloudformation template so yes i have tried putting the closing EOF all the way to start of that line and nopes did not work..gave errors with cloudformation